# Running App with Xcode takes long time to launch

Tags: xcode

Here is my problem :

When I'm testing my App using Xcode, my app freeze (and Xcode too) for a long time after displaying the Launch Image.

But when testing my app without Xcode, it runs normally.

I've noticed something : in the console of my device (Organizer / Devices / MyDevice / Console), when I launch the app from Xcode, some strange logs are displayed :

```
<Error>: Max open files: 125
```

is written like 20 times

and also :

```
<Warning>: CoreAnimation: updates deferred for too long
<Warning>: CoreAnimation: timed out fence 1954b
<Warning>: CoreAnimation: failed to receive fence reply: 10004003
```

It still stuck on those 3 last lines for a while, and then carry on the execution.

What is happening?

Comment: Does this happen with other applications too?

Comment: Yes, when my app begin to be "heavy" with many classes, about ten frameworks to import,...

Answer (score 0):

When you run app with XCode, debugger (LLVM or GDB) is attached. Debugger definitely cosumes a lot CPU and memory resource.  So it may delay threads starting by the apps. Futhermore debugger may open some extra files, resulting in the log telling you that you used up 25 files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I've checked the CPU usage while launching my app, and it doesn't rise over 45%. For the memory resources, the RAM free is about 150Mb + inactive 1 Gb. I've also performed a `purge` in my terminal, but without significant effects.

Comment: I have some logs in my app, and it looks like it freezes after the execution of the delegate `application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`